# Nuxt / VueJS Page Rendering Fine on Desktop & WiFi-connected Mobile Devices, but not on devices on 4G/5G. Any idea how to fix this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm running into a bizarre problem where page rendering works on mobile but the moment WiFi is disconnected, the images no longer load. I am baffled by this, although admittedly I am not too familiar with SSR/CR best practices.

I've even installed the `nuxt-user-agent` agent in an attempt to cut down the some unnecessary resources that are loaded, as I suspected it was a mobile device mechanism to cut down data usage.

Now I'm beginning to wonder if the javascript injection of the mouseover/hover out is playing a role in this -- but that doesn't explain why it would work on devices connected to WiFi.

Appreciate all your help. Relevant code:

The component:

```html
    <vue-masonry-wall :items="projects" :options="options">

      <template v-slot:default="{item}">
        <div  v-if="$ua.isFromPc()" class="item cursor-pointer" v-on:click="changepage(item.url)">
          <img :src="item.image" @mouseover="item.image = item.hoverimg" @mouseout="item.image = item.originalimg" style="width:100%;"/>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <img :src="item.image" style="width:100%;" v-on:click="changepage(item.url)"/>
        </div>
      </template>
    </vue-masonry-wall>
```

The data:

```js
    data() {
      return {
        projects: [
            {url: '/app/#/video/1/', image: 'foo1.jpg', hoverimg: 'foo1.webp', originalimg: 'foo1.jpg' },
            {url: '/app/#/video/2/', image: 'foo2.jpg', hoverimg: 'foo2.webp', originalimg: 'foo2.jpg' },
            {url: '/app/#/video/3/', image: 'bar1.jpg', hoverimg: 'bar1.webp', originalimg: 'bar1.jpg' },
            
            ...
        
            ]
```

Mounted:

```js
    async mounted () {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.projects = this.projects
        })}
```

Nuxt config (left in the parts I thought might be relevant):

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,
  router: {
    base: './',
    mode: 'hash'
  },
  target: 'static',
  head: {
    meta: [{
        charset: 'utf-8'
      },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'format-detection',
        content: 'telephone=no'
      }
    ],

  },

  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-tooltips.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-masonry-wall.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-skeleton-loader.js'
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/strapi',
    '@nuxtjs/markdownit',
    'nuxt-user-agent',
    ['@nuxtjs/proxy', {
      ws: false
    }]
  ],

  strapi: {
    entities: ['categories', 'projects', 'uploads'],
    url: 'theurlishere'
  }

  build: {
    publicPath: 'https://mydomain.tld/app',
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-custom-properties': false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing to note -- the image files are being pulled from a different server with a different domain (hence CORS is off for now.. I think). Obviously this is not a full production build, security/hardening will come soon. You can see my attempt at creating a proxy to the Strapi public uploads but ultimately failed and just ended up using images on the localhost.

If anyone would like to take a peek with some debugging tools: tinyurl.com/erzbh9m

Also, I'm open, actually very grateful, to anyone who suggests better practices, cause oh man, it's been years since webdev and the landscape has changed so much.

Comment: if I open the link you shared I can see that none of the images (loaded from api) are loading even on desktop Firefox

Comment: Ahh! Apologies, I'm going to assume its an authentication error with Strapi. Let me get that fixed ASAP.

Comment: @MichalLevý okay that is weird. Pretty sure I opened up authentication for the uploads/responsive images plugin to the public, but I'm getting a 404 on a VPN'd browser. Still working 100% fine on my desktop though. Let me try to debug this, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, looks like I've got some serious misconfiguration on the Nginx or Strapi end. Files are definitely there and accessible by an authenticated user in `public/uploads` but I am now ripping my hair out trying to figure out why unauthenticated users can't access it -- furthermore I thought it was weird that a 404 error is being returned instead of a 401 or at least a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Michal Levý for pointing out that none of the images were loading for him on a desktop browser.

I feel stupid.

Fixed some issues with the Nginx reverse proxy config, some middleware configs here and there, and set ENV to production, and somewhere along the way things got fixed. That was a headache.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer when you will be able to!